# Error when defining a function using a field name (`'(' expected near '['`)

Tags: lua, love2d

I have an error of compiling with lua:

```
local action = {}
action["moving"] = {}
action["zooming"] = {}
action["moving"].state = false
action["zooming"].state = false

action.list = {"moving", "zooming"}

function action["moving"].f()
  if CanAction("moving") and (love.keyboard.isDown("left") or love.keyboard.isDown("right") or love.mouse.isDown("l")) then
    if action["moving"].state == false then
      action["moving"].x, action["moving"].y = camera:mousePosition()
      action["moving"].state = true
    end
    if action["moving"].state then
      if love.mouse.isDown("l") then
        camera:setPosition(-love.mouse.getX()*camera.scaleX + action["moving"].x, -love.mouse.getY()* camera.scaleY + action["moving"].y)
      elseif love.keyboard.isDown("left") then
        camera:move(-10*camera.scaleX, 0)
      elseif love.keyboard.isDown("right") then
        camera:move(10*camera.scaleX, 0)
      end
    end
  else
    ResetAction("moving")
  end
end
```

The error is about the line when I declare the function "function action["moving"].f()", maybe because I use a table like that, thanks for your help.

Comment: (My function is complet, don't worry about that)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `action["moving"].f = function()` instead of `function action["moving"].f()` as the latter syntax is not allowed, while the former assigns an anonymous function to the field in a table.

Answer (score 4):

`t.foo` is equivalent to / syntactic sugar for `t["foo"]`.

In your case, `"moving"` and `"zooming"` are strings that are valid Lua identifiers, which means you can say `function action.moving.f( )`, which is allowed and has the same meaning.  (In particular, the field name is still a string and not somehow more fixed or anything like that – you can still say `action[some_var].f` and if `some_var == "moving"` that will get you the function you defined.)

In other cases (more complex (sub-)field names / keys), you'll have to do what Paul suggests.